# Is it possible to set up a list Title so that when clicked, the URL associated with the Title is launched?

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, url

I have a Content Editor Web Part that shows a Title (of an article) and the associated URL next to it.  Users click on the title and the Edit box opens.  They should click on the URL, but they don't.  Is there a way to set the Title field so that when it is clicked, the URL next to it launches?

Comment: Is the Title of an article an article page? or is it a list? - where are you drawing your content from?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using a Content Editor Web Part? It sounds like you're describing a List View web part...

If so, is simply hiding the Title from the view an option?

Comment: It may be a List View Web Part, although the description at the top of the Web Part edit box says "Content Editor".  The title contains a human readable description.  The URL doesn't always mean anything.

Comment: Well, that sounds like a Content Editor Web Part. :)

Where are your columns coming from? Are they simply defined in a table in the Content Editor? How do you add a new item to your list?